# Create a loop with aws credentials - Boto3

Tags: python, boto3

I'm trying to create a loop to switch for each account on ~/.aws/credentials, my aws credentials has 64 accounts, for each one i want to list all buckets.

```
# !/usr/bin/env python
import os.path
import boto3

path = "~/.aws/credentials"
full_path = os.path.expanduser(path)
print(full_path)

with open(full_path, 'r') as f:
    aws_account = f.read()

    for account in aws_account:
        s3 = boto3.client('s3')
        response = s3.list_buckets()
        buckets = [bucket['Name'] for bucket in response['Buckets']]
        print("Bucket List: %s" % buckets)
```

AWS Credentials example:

```
[TEST1]
aws_access_key_id = TEST1
aws_secret_access_key = TEST1

[TEST2]
aws_access_key_id = TEST2
aws_secret_access_key = TEST2

[TEST3]
aws_access_key_id = TEST3
aws_secret_access_key = TEST3
```

Comment: Use `session = boto3.Session(profile_name='TEST1')` Then `session.client('s3')` Docs: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/credentials.html#shared-credentials-file

Answer (score 0):

This is how I made it.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import os.path

path = "~/.aws/credentials"
full_path = os.path.expanduser(path)

aws_account = []

with open(full_path, 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines() 
    f.close()
aws_account = [line[1:-2] for line in lines if line.startswith('[') ]
#print(aws_account)
```

Comment: Hi, only-code answers aren't useful sometimes. Please consider adding a description of the code.